# Postfix mail sending issue with SMTP Authentication using SASL

Tags: authentication, smtp, sasl

I have configured an SMTP server on my Ubuntu server using Postfix, and I am encountering issues with SMTP authentication. Emails sent directly through the server are successful. However, when I attempt to authenticate via SMTP using SASL, I am facing authentication failures.

Here are the details of my configuration:

SMTP Server: Ubuntu with Postfix Authentication Method: SASL (PLAIN)

Testing Methods:

*SWAKS Test: swaks --to [recipient] --from [sender] --server [smtp_server] --auth-user [username] --auth-password [password] --auth PLAIN*
Result: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

testsaslauthd Test:

*testsaslauthd -u username -p password Result: Success*

Expected Outcome: Successful authentication using SASL for sending emails via SMTP.

I have double-checked the username and password, and they are accurate. The server's authentication settings are configured for PLAIN. I am puzzled by the inconsistency between the success with testsaslauthd and the failure with SWAKS.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be causing the authentication failure specifically with SASL? Are there any common pitfalls or configurations that I might be missing?

Any assistance or guidance on resolving this SMTP authentication problem with SASL would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time and expertise!